# Scala - From tuple to map

Tags: scala, dictionary

*I hope it is okay if I post solved problems and ask for a more beautiful solution, so that I can see how it is done correctly*

I wanted a list of all process names mapped with a ProcessID. Something like `"notepad.exe" -> 4242`
Ofc there can be multiple instances so it should be something like `"notepad.exe" -> List(4242,7171)`

I have a method which gives me a tuple

```
private def extractProcess(s: String): (String, Int) = {
    val process = s.split(" ").filterNot(str => str == "")
    (process(0), process(1).toInt)
}
```

output would be `("Notepad.exe",4242)`

processList containt the raw string from windows tasklist which looks something like this

```
svchost.exe                   4464 Services                   0        47.656 K
```

Now I want to create a map with all processes and I have done it like this

```
val process: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map()
    processList.drop(5).map(s => {
      val element = extractProcess(s)
      if (process contains element._1) {
        val p = process get element._1
        process(element._1) = p.get ::: List(element._2)
      } else {
        process(element._1) = List(element._2)
      }
    })
```

*I droped the first 5 elements because they are not needed*

Now the output would look like this

```
...
(tasklist.exe,List(5036))
(NLClientApp.exe,List(2812))
(wininit.exe,List(444))
(SearchFilterHost.exe,List(5476))
(svchost.exe,List(656, 732, 928, 964, 992, 1036, 1140, 1360, 2168, 4464, 4764, 5048))
...
```

Which is what I wanted to do.
Are there better ways of creating the map?

I always think more imperative than functional, it is hard to think different.

Comment: As for your disclaimer, there is [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) site (it's better suited for questions like this, but on the other hand it has much less visitors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be made simpler like this:

```
processList.drop(5).map(extractProcess).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: processList only contains the strings from the tasklist (windows), I need to call `extractProcess` to retrieve the tuple.

Comment: Yeah. Missed that. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

```
processList.drop(5).map(extractProcess).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```